# Rails routing race condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Has anyone come across race condition issue like this?

```
Started GET "//product_schemas/show?product_id=6aa11af8-9d77-4109-ad5e-9ec91200bfc1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-11 09:46:00 +1000

Started GET "//products/6aa11af8-9d77-4109-ad5e-9ec91200bfc1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-11 09:46:00 +1000

Processing by V1::ProductsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"6aa11af8-9d77-4109-ad5e-9ec91200bfc1"}

Processing by V1::ProductsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"6aa11af8-9d77-4109-ad5e-9ec91200bfc1"}
```

Both the requests were processed by ProductsController but there is ProductSchemasController which should have processed the /product_schemas/show call.

Relevant routings are

```
resources :product_schemas, only: [] do
  collection do
    get 'show' => 'product_schemas#show'
  end
end
```

and

```
resources :products do
end
```

Comment: By race condition you mean, `"//product_schemas/show?product_id=6aa11af8-9d77-4109-ad5e-9ec91200bfc1" ` goes to correct controller when the other request is not happening at the same time?  If so, then can you double check the logs and make sure there is no entry for product_schemas controller?

Comment: The 'show' is default a member route, Please rename the show to other name which is not in rails default routes.

Comment: Did you run `rake routes` and check that your routes are drawn as expected?

Comment: yes routing is correct when calls are made synchrously. @VijayAgrawal

Comment: Will try that @xiaocui

Comment: rake routes is fine and it also works when calls are made synchronously. @WizardofOgz